# ofstream outputs in debug but not run

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt, ofstream

I have a very simple C++ program with a very simple project setup, but when I run the program I get no output. If I run the program in debug mode, it works perfectly. I am using Eclipse Kepler CDT 32 bit on windows with MinGW. I am somewhat new to eclipse, so it's probably something I did wrong.

The program is:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

ofstream outfile("testdata.txt");

int main()
{
    outfile << "Program Start\n";
    cout << "Program Start\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Help!

Comment: Do you mean theres no output in the file or in the console or both?

Comment: No output in console and no file is created.

Comment: Update: Still no fix in Eclipse, but I tried running it from cmd and from msys. From cmd I get an error "The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer."  From msys it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the program quickly opens and then closes before you can see the output on the screen, then you can just run your program from any shell (CMD on Windows, bash on Linux, etc.). That way, it won't exit once your program ends and you can see the results.

Make sure also that you flush/close your `ofstream` before your program exits.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is rather not releted to c++ itself. You should check if via "cmd" typying it in "launch menu" after you click start. Find the path of your program, then run it.

For the very beginning it is recommended to spend a few hours with terminal(cmd). To know how things works. After that you will be independent - you will be able to write the code in any IDE. Also simple trick to make it working is to use  `std::cin.get()` . It is prefered to system("pause").

Answer (score -1):

You open the `testdata.txt` file using the relative path.

And the created file may be created in the project binary output path, where the executable located in.
You can use `everything` software to check whether a file is created and its created path.

[everything](https://www.voidtools.com/)

For example, you can type your output file name `testdata.txt` into `everything` software to see where output file created.And check if the `testdata.txt` created in a wrong path or directory.

[image: search example in everything]